Обновления Windows
может подскажите,что это за обновления Windows10 Pro(версия 22H2) в Центре обновлений и стоит ли их устанавливать:
Intel - SoftwareComponent - 1.71.99.0
Intel - SoftwareComponent - 2408.5.4.0
Intel - System - 2406.5.5.0

(сначала были в необязательных-потом перешли в обязательные)
На сайте Intel ничего подобного нет!

The iCLS Client is the Intel® Trusted Connect Service Client and it is part of the Intel® Management Engine.
